# Unable to set cookie cross-site for 127.0.0.1

Tags: firefox, cookies, samesite, cross-site

Trying to set up local dev environment. Task is to enable cross-site cookie to be set in browser. I intentionally disabled recent Samesite settings in Firefox:

network.cookie.sameSite.laxByDefault : false

network.cookie.sameSite.noneRequiresSecure : false

HTTP Response looks following:

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
date: Tue, 25 Jan 2022 21:30:08 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 109
content-security-policy: default-src http://127.0.0.1  'self' 'unsafe-inline';style-src http://127.0.0.1 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; script-src http://127.0.0.1 'self' 'unsafe-inline';font-src http://127.0.0.1 'self' data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
expect-ct: max-age=0
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
x-download-options: noopen
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
referrer-policy: no-referrer
x-xss-protection: 0
access-control-allow-origin: http://127.0.0.1
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: GET,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Length
access-control-max-age: 3600
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With
set-cookie: access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImhlbWlkaXQ2NTdAZHVrZW9vLmNvbSIsImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6IkpheSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiT2tvY2hhIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQzMTQ2MjA4LCJleHAiOjE2NDU3MzgyMDh9.Mbl3uy6OelZd9lRUoUzz3q_8nuaOZ-tvAGIgQ3NX3qQ; Path=/; HttpOnly
etag: W/"6d-8J7FkpDLio+d8AurKXy9hZmOwMg"
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Cookie is not set. Any ideas would help.